# How do I switch between technologies in IT industry

Tags: career-development, careers, technology, career-switch

I am working with a web development company and have 2+ years of experience of programming with PHP and overall 3 years of working in the IT industry. For long term goals and stability I want to try with mobile application development, Ruby, Python etc as these technologies are currently in demand and enhance my learning capabilities as well.

I am an engg CS graduate with an experience, so to grab the concepts in these technologies will not going to be a big deal but the problem is that I really need to switch jobs for this, as my current company is not so big to give me the opportunity to test these technologies.

My other concern is that if I try for example RoR then I would assume as a fresher my PHP knowledge goes in vain. Let me know how do I proceed further for a better career, what are online learning options. Any suggestions and recommendations are highly appreciated. I'm located in India.

Comment: Don't use backticks for emphasis please, backticks are only meant for code.

Comment: @YannisRizos thx for the info.. habit from SO ;)

Comment: @swapnesh: Exact same rule applies on SO.  :P  Backticks are for code, or for other things that must be entered verbatim.  If you want to emphasize, use asterisks or underscores (which italicize and/or bold the text, providing proper emphasis, depending on how many you use).

Comment: We can not decide for you what to do with your career.  You are asking for a list of suggestions on options which is by definition not constructive. I realize this is a real problem you face but I do not know how to make a constructive question out of it.  You are asking about a better career but a career where you make more money or go farther but are miserable does not fit my definition of better.  It is too subjective and personal of a decision that only you can really make for yourself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A lot of learning is done on the job, to be sure. But accept that we all have to invest some amount of our non-working hours in keeping up to date and learning new technologies. You say you want to learn Ruby, what's stopping you? Just download it and start building something, anything. That's how you start learning. Then when you're comfortable enough with it that you think you could start building commercial solutions, put it on your CV as "spare time projects".

It's also a lot easier to get an opportunity to use it your current job if you can say that you already know it and that you have identified some area or application where it would be a huge gain.

Comment: +1 for the "spare time projects", interesting thing to add on resume, but what about if i apply in these technologies..would i consider as a fresher or something else?

Comment: @swapnesh Depends on who's on the other side of the question. Personally, I would consider you as having knowledge but no proven, professional experience. So junior, but not a novice - assuming you could prove your competence to my satisfaction.

Comment: yes ur right with the observation that's why asking from seasoned professionals that how could i move to next steps (SO is good and i am following that but looking more to expand my knowledge spectrum)

Comment: @swapnesh: If you have commercial experience writing software and non-commercial experience using the technologies we use,  I would consider you for a job. You'd be tested on your knowledge accordingly, but commercial experience is important because it means you know the industry, which applies regardless of the language used.

Comment: @pdr thx for the offering:) will really look for everything that enhance my learning capabilities :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to get direct experience and high value on-the-job training in new technologies; join a start-up.

Small, new tech companies do not care about rigid job descriptions; if they take you on in one role, but they need something else done and you are willing to devote the time to it, you will get the chance.  Even when working in your core area, you will have the opportunity to make decisions which, in a larger company, would be handed down to you by an architect or controlled by another team.  This is why one year's experience in a start-up is often worth 5 years anywhere else.  I know people who have gone from being an intern to being a team manager within two years at a start-up.  Made an incredible difference to their skills, their confidence and their earning ability.

It is, of course, risky.

Comment: this solution might not be acceptable when you are an experience guy as this sounds risky money wise

Comment: @swapnesh There's less risk for experienced professionals; they have more knowledge with which to judge the chances of success and know they can use their experience and record to get a new job if it fails.

Comment: @swapnesh but you are a relative newcomer, trying to expand his experience, so what does it mean for *you*?

Comment: @itsbruce I agree that in small companies you have a chance to "think" but it has some drawbacks. For example, at first you start doing awful things (actually, writing huge and, of course, bad code) and there's almost nobody to stop you. I had to re-factor my first project in the company where I work now and after completely losing 2 days, I've rewritten code because there were bugs everywhere.

Comment: @PLB A lot depends on the mix of people at the start.  If there is a core of some experienced people, they will know which compromises and bodges are acceptable and which things just have to be done right from the beginning (because to bodge them would be to cause too much pain later on).

Answer (score 1):

Already there is a great answer by @pap. If you are really serious about learning new technology, then why don't you start today.

Some kind of certification in the new technologies will definitely help you a bit. As far as the fresher thing is concerned, you will be counted as a fresher in new technology, but your technology experience could never be ignored. Your 3 years experience will show up that you are not a novice in the technology world.

Comment: certification doesn't help to be honest !