# what should I have to do to change my career to artificial intelligence?

Tags: job-change

I'm a software architect exhausted to do applications that only read data, store data, update data, show data and delete data.

I've been programming for more that 17 years doing desktop applications, web applications (I have them), windows services, backend services, web services, etc...) and now I want to change.

I've been doing courses for Machine Learning at Coursera, Deep Learning at Udacity and Python reading books and following tutorials. But it seems that this not enough. Companies want 3 or more years of experience working on a same job to hire. But if I'm not hired I won't get the experience to get hired.

I think they don't like people that learn but they own and do thing at home. They are always asking about experience in a real job, not at home.

I have created a github repository to store all the programs I did, to show companies that I've been doing programs but I don't think it is enough because I haven't got any interview jet.

What do I should do to change my career to artificial intelligence?

Or maybe this is a question about how to get job experience if I don't have a job.

**UPDATE:**

Some of you have put this question on hold. I want to clarify why I have asked this here:

1. First I checked Meta Stack Exchange to know where to ask, I've found this question: [Where can you ask about Career advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/where-can-you-ask-about-career-advice#).
2. On-Hold topic said: *"Questions asking for advice on a specific choice [...] are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else"*. I don't think so. This question is more about: *how to get job experience if I don't have a job*. That I said previously.

Very often it is so difficult to ask something on Stack Exchange. There are a lot of rules to don't ask off topic question. This is why I check **a question** with **27 points** before ask it and after that I get this question on-hold. I don't understand.

Comment: [How do I switch between technologies in IT industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/how-do-i-switch-between-technologies-in-it-industry). Expect that no-one will look at your GitHub account and make something substantial enough that you can put on your resume.

Comment: Do you have enough knowledge about statistics? If you do, you should be able to get interviews soon. If you don't, go back to school to learn Math and stats.

Comment: @scaaahu I think my problem is that companies do not think I have that knowledge because I've never worked on those fields.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and don't telling why.

Comment: @scaaahu The amount of knowledge required about stats and maths (beyond say high school and some undergrad) will depend heavily on what type of AI you want to work on and whether you want to get involved in research. Knowledge by itself doesn't lead to interviews, but rather it is the ability to properly present or showcase that knowledge which does.

Comment: You have answered your question yourself. "my problem is that companies do not think I have that knowledge because I've never worked on those fields." - as you say "you have never worked on these fields"; taking courses is not the same thing. You didn't mention what type of projects you did and put on github. But, it may indeed help to get an AI- or stats-oriented degree to shortcut that instead of writing open-source AIs and hope someone will pick it up.

Comment: ... and hope someone... Please, I'm don't asking what I did. I'm asking what I should do. I haven't answered my question saying what I did. And hope is like a miracle. I don't think things work like this: waiting a miracle.

Comment: @VansFannel, None of your repositories on Github are public. How do you give potential employers access to those repositories? Do you ask for their github account before you give them access? Do you zip your projects and then email them? Do you wait until the interview? Also, how many of those projects do involve deep learning? Currently, you seem to be splitting your efforts between Unreal and Deep Learning. I'd suggest that you pick only one and go for it. And obviously, deep learning is the hot area right now, not Unreal.

Comment: https://github.com/viacognita All of them are public. You can access and download it or clone it or check it. I don't understand what do you mean with they are not public.

Comment: That has just two repositories, "Unreal" and "Udacity". Neither are impressive.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks but your comment doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I was talking about knowledge, not experience. You can acquire experience by working on something real. However, you need to go to school to gain math and stats knowledge. Of course, you can study math/stats at home, but the companies will not recognize them. They only recognize the degree you get from the school.

Comment: It does not matter how good you code on GitHub looks. The code can only show that you can code something. But, the real AI problem needs to be solved by Math/stats. AI is a new field, not too many people can claim that they have 3 or more years of experience. Those companies are looking for people fresh from schools who have acquired good math/stats knowledge.

Comment: I have updated my question because some of you have put it on-hold.

Comment: Voted to re-open.

Comment: @scaaahu I have asked the same question in another forum and there they have suggested me the same: study statistics, linear algebra, etc.